# Should I use Panels to create boxed/gallery of summaries layout? (See picture)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, panel

[image: Desired View]

Hi I would like to create a page to render the above in a Bootstrap website that I'm currently working on.  Would Bootstrap Panel's be the best approach to create this, I would have to override the border, horizontal rule, and background colours. I believe this would be easy enough to do but is there an easier approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the box in AdminLte combined with the columns of bootstrap, and just changing the background-color of the box should give you your desired outcome. Something like the following.

```
<style>
    .box .orange{
        background-color: orange;
    }

    .box .blue{
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="box box-solid orange">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Title of panel</h3>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <p>27 people booked in</p>
                    <p>25 people attented</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="box box-solid blue">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Title of panel</h3>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <p>27 people booked in</p>
                    <p>25 people attented</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```